# AngularJS boolean value always returns true in scope

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

So I have a state which takes two specific parameters (subjectID & isCalc):

```
  .state('tabsController.formulaPicker', {
    url: '/my/:subjectID?withCalc',
    views: {
      'tab1': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/formulaPicker.html',
        controller: 'formulaPickerCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

& In my controller I have:

```
  .controller('formulaPickerCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, $http) {
    $scope.subjectID = $stateParams.subjectID;
    $scope.subjectName = '';
    $scope.withCalc = $stateParams.withCalc;
    $scope.formulas = [];

    $http.get('../Data.json')
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // Alerts correct value
        alert($scope.withCalc);
        // Always returns true
        $scope.subjectSet = ($scope.withCalc) ? data.subjects : data.subjects_no_calc;
        $scope.subjectName = $scope.subjectSet[$scope.subjectID].name;
        $scope.formulas = $scope.subjectSet[$scope.subjectID].formulas;
      })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      })
      .then(function (result) {
      });
  })
```

But in the line where I declare the scope's `subjectSet` value, I have a ternary operator that checks the `isCalc` bool value, it returns a specific set of data from the json file I'm requesting. Every time I load the controller it alerts the isCalc value, which I want & is correct. But the ternary expression always returns true, even though it alerted false. This causes me to return the wrong set of values.

I two `ui-sref` properties from the first controller:

`ui-sref="tabsController.formulaPicker({subjectID: $index, withCalc: true})"`

for the first section
&

`"tabsController.formulaPicker({subjectID: $index, withCalc: false})"`

for the second section.

Remember it alerts the correct value but the ternary expression always returns true no matter what.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like `$scope.withCalc` is *String* type. But must be *Boolean* type. Try this `$scope.withCalc = $stateParams.withCalc=="true"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether `$scope.withCals` is not a String Object. You may need to convert it explicitly to Boolean.